# Does Glassfish server consist of a webserver also?

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, jakarta-ee, glassfish

According to the defintions I have read a `web server` is something which can serve http requests (e.g Apache).

A `web container` is something which can serve servlets and JSPs etc. Since Tomcat can both serve http requests and also serve servlets and JSPs it is considered as both a web server and a web container.

Application servers like Jboss, Glassfish are fully fledged java EE servers which also include other containers apart from the web container.

Now in order for an application server like Glassfish to work on its own, it also needs a web server(an http server) built into it. Therefore it should contain a webserver to work on its won, and if it doesn't contain a webserver built into it, there should be a way to plug existing web servers like apache to this application server.

What is the actual implementation? does it include a webserver or we should plug webservers into these java EE application servers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it includes a full web tier. The Java Servlet spec covers much of this.